# Matplotlib dulls the color red in the plot

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, colors, spyder

When I plot a graph in Spyder using Matplotlib, the color red will be sometimes be dulled. For example,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0,10,100)
y = 2*x

plt.plot(x,y, color = 'r', linewidth = 10)
plt.show()
```

will produce the image

[image]

instead of

[image]

If I restart Spyder after seeing the dulled red color, then it produces the good plot with the normal red color. I've only noticed this when plotting with the color red. The versions I'm using are Python 3.7.0, Spyder 3.3.4, IPython 7.2.0, and Matplotlib 3.0.2. I'm also using a Mac Mojave, if that's relevant.

Comment: It's also rounding off the ends of the line. Odd!

Comment: Apparently you execute some code beforehands, of which we have no knowledge. So you need to look at that code and see what it does or provide that code in the question such that people can track down where it comes from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Someplace before executing your code you will have a line saying something like

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.set(style="white")
```

or similar.

Complete code:

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.set(style="white")

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0,10,100)
y = 2*x

plt.plot(x,y, color = 'r', linewidth = 10)
plt.show()
```

[image]

The explanation is that [`seaborn.set`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.set.html) updates the colors if its `color_codes` argument is set to True (which is the default).

> `color_codes` : bool
>           If `True` and `palette` is a seaborn palette, remap the shorthand
>           color codes (e.g. "b", "g", "r", etc.) to the colors from this palette.

There is also an [example](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.set_color_codes.html#seaborn.set_color_codes) in the seaborn documentation.

So you can use

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.set(style="white", color_codes=False)
```

to get

[image]

or just not use `.set` at all.

Comment: Thank you for another detailed answer :) The code I posted is actually all the code I ran in that script. However, I do have the Seaborn style set the way you describe in a different script that I ran in the same session. Does IPython/Spyder remember the setting throughout the time it's open? And even when I run both scripts, I don't always encounter this issue.

Comment: It totally depends on your spyder settings; but I think by default scripts are run all in the same IPython console; so in that case the python session stays open and will of course "remember" previous settings. Spyder offers options to start a new console each time a script is run or even to use the system console instead - this is up to you to configure the way you like it.

Answer (score 1):

When I run your code, I get the second plot with normal red color. I am using Matplotlib 3.0.3 version. 
BTW, You can always play around color by specifying rgb in your code (rgb should be in the range of 0.0 to 1.0) to get the color you like:

```
plt.plot(x,y, color = (0.95, 0, 0), linewidth = 10)
```